# OpenGL: Using VBO with std::vector

Tags: c++, opengl, pointers, stdvector, vbo

I'm trying to load an object and use VBO and glDrawArrays() to render it. The problem is that a simple float pointer like `float f[]={...}` does not work in my case, because I passed the limit of values that this pointer can store. So my solution was to use a vector. And it's not working...

Here is my code:

```
unsigned int vbo;
vector<float*> vert;

...
vert.push_back(new float(i*size));
vert.push_back(new float(height*h));
vert.push_back(new float(j*size));
...

glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vert), &vert, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

and to render:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 3);
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

I'm having problem on the `glBufferData()` where the 3rd parameter is `const GLvoid *data`. I'm passing `&vert` but It's not working.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You want to do:

```
unsigned int vbo;
vector<float> vert;

...
vert.push_back(i*size);
vert.push_back(height*h);
vert.push_back(j*size);
...

glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vert.size() * sizeof(float), vert.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

It is always good to read the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). Also, I would suggest you pick up a good C++ book, which probably would be a good way for you to avoid doing mistakes like these.

Comment: It is better to use `vert.size() * sizeof(float)` for the size parameter for better portability.

Comment: @Kevin In fact just using vert.size() doesn't work at all. Only 1/4 of the VBO will be rendered

Answer (score 5):

Remember to check if you have C++11 or `vert.data` won't compile.

If you look at the `std::vector` doc you'll that `std::vector::data()` is tagged with C++11.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/data/

If you don't have C++11 you can do the following:

```
unsigned int vbo;
vector<float> vert;

...
vert.push_back(i*size);
vert.push_back(height*h);
vert.push_back(j*size);
...

glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vert.size(), &vert[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

Taking a reference to the first element of a vector gives you a pointer to the data itself.

Comment: I tried it already, but it didn't work. But I have C++ 11 so `data` was the solution

Comment: Did you try `&vert[0]`? Which compiler are you using? Before C++11 all my code use this form and works fine.

Comment: Oh, I found the solution. The correct way to do it is `vert.data()` or `&(vert[0])`. `&vert[0]` didn't work for me

Comment: Better to use *vert.size() * sizeof(float)* or you will draw only the part of VAO !

Answer (score 1):

I might be a bit late, but for anyone else who needs help on this, you have to obtain a pointer from the start of the data which can be done with `&vert.front()` or `&vert[0]`

So it should look something like this:

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vert.size() * sizeof(float), &vert.front(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```