# Create dynamic array of objects for VBO

Tags: c++, arrays, opengl, vbo, dynamic-arrays

I am trying to create dynamic array of objects and then use it for VBO.

```
Vector3f Vertices[] = new Vector3f[size];
/* 
    initialization
*/

glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Vertices), Vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

But i have the following error: 
`initialization with '{...}' expected for aggregate object`
So, how can i do this? I suppose it must be possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My former comment: You want `sizeof(Vector3f) * size` rather than `sizeof(Vertices)`, i.e., the size of the data in bytes, in your call to `glBufferData`.

---

1/. Use: `Vector3f *vertices = new Vector3f[size];`

`vertices` is a pointer a an array of Vector3f (with suitable padding between elements if required, given by `sizeof(Vector3f)`. Each `Vector3f` element is constructed using `Vector3f`'s default constructor.

2/. Consider managing your data with: `std::vector<Vector3f> vertices (size);` - so you can manage and operate on [**vector**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) containers rather than managing pointers. Since std::vector data has contiguous access, you can use:

`glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size() * sizeof(Vector3f), vertices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);`

Should you change the size of the vertices (Vector3f) container, you let the `std::vector<>::size()` take care the number of elements.

Obviously, you don't need any explicit `delete` here. Once the Vector3f container passes out of scope, it's automatically destructed. Haven't even touched on all the advantage of generic functions that can operate on the container... merging, reversing, sorting ... just a few things you get for free.

Comment: @user3051029 - feel free to accept the answer if it satisfies. If you're not aware already, when you set a `VertexAttribPointer`, and there is padding between `Vector3f` elements, you might need to be careful with 'stride'. e.g., `glVertexAttribPointer(index, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vector3f), (void *) 0);` - unless you *know* the data is packed.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to use std::vector or std::list in place of traditional C array.

Here is a reference

[OpenGL: Using VBO with std::vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14234361/opengl-using-vbo-with-stdvector)